# PresentationFramework.pdb not found

Tags: c#, wpf, config

Suddenly Visual Studio says that PresentationFramework.pdb is not found.
The InnerException says that something is wrong with line 4 in the Application.exe.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" Type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Application.Properties.Settings" Type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <userSettings>
    <Application.Properties.Settings>

    </Application.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Reading the Presentation Framework or clean and rebuild project doesn't work.

Problem solved I just had to rename `Type` to `type`.